# Thymeleaf + static resource + @ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In Spring Boot, I've got the simplest controller ever, returning my view name:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "helloworld.html";
    }
}
```

My `helloworld.html` file is placed in `resources/static` directory:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello world!
</body>
</html>
```

And it works just fine - typing `localhost:8080/hello` prints "Hello world!" in browser.

Then I add Thymeleaf dependency to `pom.xml`, rerun app and get `TemplateInputException` when typing the same address in browser. Which is fine I guess, as now the resources are searched by default in `resources/templates` directory.

What I find weird, is when I add `@ReponseBody` annotation to controller method:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello() {
        return "helloworld.html";
    }
}
```

Everything works again, I get "Hello world!" in browser. But as I know, the `@ResponseBody` annotation is to put the returned value as a body of the response. So why it miraculously caused that the view file can be found again?

Comment: maybe you did not rebuild your project? Because it absolutely should return  `helloworld.html`

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and I do not get "Hello World" as response with thymeleaf and html placed under static. But I get printed the string

"helloworld.html" with annotated @ResponseBody

as your controller method returns a String which in your case is the misleading "helloworld.html"